# append jquery mouseover to be compatible with tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a 'mega nav' which appears on mouseover that contains a small set of tabs but would like to make it compatible with tablet devices. I'm not very familiar with coding for both at this point, more often than not i'm working with a responsive template, whereas here i am not.

Can the following be appended to handle both using touchstart or do i have to start from scratch?

```
    $(function() {
        var $items = $('#vtab_used>ul>li');
        $items.mouseover(function() {
            $items.removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var index = $items.index($(this));
            $('#vtab_used>div').hide().eq(index).show();
        }).eq(0).mouseover();
    });
```

Comment: Mouseover doesn't make sense with a touchscreen.  You will need to combine a mouseover with a touchstart/touchmove/touchend event to simulate a mouseover.

Comment: What do you mean by 'mega nav'. Is this some open-source library?

Comment: no, its a pure css navigation. basically just displays a giant div below the width of my menu when you hover over a menu item, i'll be trying to make that guy compatible next.